# add class to trigger jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'm using d3js to create a number of circles (nodes) that should trigger different overlays (like modals) when clicked on.

The overlay is triggered when a class is clicked:

```
$(".overlay01").click(function(){
      setTimeout(
        function() {
            $(".location-modal").toggleClass("active");
        },500);
});
```

I am adding the class to the d3 node from data:

```
var nodes = svg.selectAll("circle")
                .data(nodes)
                .enter()
                .append("a")

                .attr("class", function(d) { return d.class; })

                .append("circle")
                .attr("r", 20)
                .style("fill", "#fff")
                .style("cursor", "pointer")
                .call(force.drag);
```

Now... in the browser inspector I can see that the node (circle) has had the class added (in this case

```
<a class="overlay01">
```

yet when I click on it nothing happens?!

This is far as I have got:
http://unit60.com/karte/test06.html

What am I missing??

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you are applying the "click" event before the element is created. Try using delegation so that the event will be tied to `body` and then each time the event triggers the delegator will look to see if its child with class "overlay01" was clicked.

```
$("body").on("click", ".overlay01", function(){
      setTimeout(
        function() {
            $(".location-modal").toggleClass("active");
        },500);
});
```

Another solution is to wait until ".overlay01" is loaded before adding the event by use of `$(document).ready(callback)` or another method.

Comment: that doesn't appear to be the problem :(
I have a link in the html with the same class and it triggers the modal fine, just not from the node... so frustrating ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery to manipulate svg is quite a pain if possible at all. Especially `.attr()` and `toggleClass()` are not working properly on svg content. They were designed to work with html and are causing troubles when being applied to other namespaces. You should stick to d3 to get things working:

```
d3.selectAll(".overlay01")
  .on("click", function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      d3.selectAll(".location-modal")
        .classed("active", function() { 
          return !d3.select(this).classed("active");   // This will actually toggle the class
        });
    },500);
  });
```

I tried this code on my own scratch pad and it might need some refinement, but it should get you started

Comment: Looking at your example I can't find a single place where you embedded the solution I posted. There is still a lot of jQuery stuff around doing `attr()` and `toggleClass()` which will not work for the reasons stated in my answer. Try to incorporate the proposed changes. Providing a stripped down fiddle might also be valuable in finding a solution to your problem.

Comment: here is a stripped down fiddle... the problem is it works (LOL)... so I am trying to figure out now what I am doing wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/unit60/efm1pxrz/

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. It does attach the click handlers, though, but as mentioned it fails toggling classes using jQuery. I have [updated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/altocumulus/efm1pxrz/1/) to provide a working example which still has some jQuery in it. Personally, I would prefer to leave it to d3 which would end up in adopting the answer I proposed (I also [updated](http://jsfiddle.net/altocumulus/efm1pxrz/2/) your fiddle to have it this way).

Comment: Ok... i see what you mean now... thanks for the help :)

Comment: Ive made some changes to the original idea and have it working how I imagined it... http://jsfiddle.net/unit60/oztw93cx/
but now I am having problems creating a group from the node so that I can append text and change the size of the node ("circle") on mouseover... as it is tied into the projection I guess?! 
Help :(

Comment: That looks really nice! Since this problem seems to be solved I'd like to suggest opening a new question to tackle the next problems.

Comment: Will do :)
I guess the problem was more to do with how the elements were being collated:
 /* Define the main worker or execution function */
function makeDiag(error, nodes, links, table) {
    /* Draw the node labels first */
So I just started with another approach!

Comment: PS: opened new issues here if you care to input ;)
http://stackoverflow.com/q/29517199/4564984